# How to excess scipy.solve_ivp solution.y_events?

Tags: python, events, scipy, ode, montecarlo

I need to simulate a penalty where the ball shoots in every direction. For this I use solve_ivp and I terminate the integration when the ball crosses the backline. When this happens I want to use the values found when the integration stops to see if the ball at that point is within the dimensions of the goal (and count it as a goal). However, solution.y does not give the required precision that I want. The desired values are within solution.y_events, however, I can't seem to be able to get receive them. I also can't find information about this online. My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import constants
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



#### Constants

# Number of simulations
number_of_penalty_shots = 10

# Angle of the shots
theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2.0*np.pi, number_of_penalty_shots)
phi = np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, number_of_penalty_shots)

# Velocity of the ball
v_magnitude = 80

### Starting Position Ball (defined as the penalty stip)
pos_x = 0.0
pos_y = 0.0
pos_z = 0.0

in_position = np.array([pos_x, pos_y, pos_z]) # Inital position in m


def homo_magnetic_field(t, vector):
    vx = vector[3] # dx/dt = vx
    vy = vector[4] # dy/dt = vy
    vz = vector[5] # dz/dt = vz   
        
    # ax = -0.05*vector[3] # dvx/dt = ax
    # ay = -0.05*vector[4] # dvy/dy = ay
    # az = -0.05*vector[5] - constants.g #dvz/dt = az
    
    ax = 0
    ay = 0
    az = 0
        
    dvectordt = (vx,vy,vz,ax,ay,az)
    return(dvectordt)

def goal(t, vector):
    return vector[1] - 11

def own_goal(t,vector):
    return vector[1] + 100

def ground(t,vector):
    return vector[2]

goal.terminal=True
own_goal.terminal=True

def is_it_goal(vector):
    if vector.status == 1:
        if (vector.y[1][len(vector.y[1])-1] > 0) and (-3.36 < vector.y[0][len(vector.y[1])-1] < 3.36) and (vector.y[2][len(vector.y[1])-1] < 2.44):
            print("GOAAAAAAAAAAAAL!")
        elif (vector.y[1][len(vector.y[1])-1] < 0) and (-3.36 < vector.y[0][len(vector.y[1])-1] < 3.36) and (vector.y[2][len(vector.y[1])-1] < 2.44):
            print("Own goal?! Why?")
        else:  print("Awwwwh")
    else: print("Not even close, lol")


# Integrating

time_range = (0.0, 10**2)

for i in range(number_of_penalty_shots):
    v_x = v_magnitude*np.sin(phi[i])*np.cos(theta[i])
    v_y = v_magnitude*np.sin(phi[i])*np.sin(theta[i])
    v_z = v_magnitude*np.cos(phi[i])
    in_velocity = np.array([v_x, v_y, v_z])
    initial_point = np.array([in_position, in_velocity])
    start_point = initial_point.reshape(6,)
    
    solution = integrate.solve_ivp(homo_magnetic_field , time_range, start_point,events=(goal, own_goal))
    is_it_goal(solution)
```

Here I want to change vector.y[1][len(vector.y[1])-1] into something like vector.y_events...

Comment: You can shorten `vector.y[1][len(vector.y[1])-1]` to `vector.y[1][-1]`. You need to evaluate `solution.status`, with the meaning in `solution.message` to find out if there was an event. `.t_events[k]` is the list of trigger times for event no. `k`, `.y_events[k]` contains the list of the corresponding points (incompatible with the formatting of `solution.y`).

Comment: .y_events consists only holds two inputs. That is my problem, unfortunately. i.e.: y.events = [array([], dtype=float64), array([[  88.53280031, -100.        ,  59.34496498,   48.46126737,          -54.73820686,   32.48436969]])], y_events[0] = [], and, y_events[1] = [[  88.53280031 -100.           59.34496498   48.46126737  -54.73820686    32.48436969]]. From y_events[1] I would like to get the first and third values to check if they are inside the goal.

Comment: If `len(sol.t_events[k]>0)`, then you can evaluate `sol.y_events[k][0,[0,2]]` to get the first and third components.

Comment: Don't know what you did, but it works! Thanks a lot!!!